# IPv6 LAN stops routing / responding during bootup

Tags: ipv6, pfsense

I recently set up an HE tunnel to add IPv6 support to my network. When the router boots "Starting Firewall" rolls by twice on the console.  After the first time, I'm able to ping the router's LAN IPv6 address from a computer on the network, as well as external IPv6 addresses (facebook). I'm also able to ping nodes on the LAN network without an issue.   After the second  time it rolls by I'm unable to reach the router via its IPv6 address from any node on the network and the router is unable to reach any ipv6 address on the LAN.  Traceroutes to any node on the LAN network give me !A from the router's address. From the router I'm able to get to any external IPv6 through the tunnel.

I've verified IPv6 is enabled in Advanced Settings.
 I've tried adding any/any rules to the firewall. 
 I've tried completely disabling the firewall temporarily.
 I've tried blowing away the tunnel and just setting up an IPv6 lan with the same issue. 
 I've verified my routing tables are correct.

At this point any help would be appreciated because I'm completely at a loss.

When it stops working the system.log looks like this:

```
Mar 28 12:11:57 firewall kernel: ..
Mar 28 12:11:59 firewall check_reload_status: updating dyndns WAN_DHCP
Mar 28 12:11:59 firewall check_reload_status: Restarting ipsec tunnels
Mar 28 12:11:59 firewall check_reload_status: Restarting OpenVPN tunnels/interfaces
Mar 28 12:11:59 firewall check_reload_status: Reloading filter
Mar 28 12:12:00 firewall check_reload_status: updating dyndns WANGW
Mar 28 12:12:00 firewall check_reload_status: Restarting ipsec tunnels
Mar 28 12:12:00 firewall check_reload_status: Restarting OpenVPN tunnels/interfaces
Mar 28 12:12:00 firewall check_reload_status: Reloading filter
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: .done.
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: ipfw2 (+ipv6) initialized, divert loadable, nat loadable, default to accept, logging disabled
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: DUMMYNET 0 with IPv6 initialized (100409)
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: load_dn_sched dn_sched FIFO loaded
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: load_dn_sched dn_sched QFQ loaded
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: load_dn_sched dn_sched RR loaded
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: load_dn_sched dn_sched WF2Q+ loaded
Mar 28 12:12:23 firewall kernel: load_dn_sched dn_sched PRIO loaded
```

My routing tables look correct:

```
Routing tables

Internet6:
Destination                       Gateway                       Flags      Netif Expire
::1                               link#8                        UH          lo0
MYIPV6PREFIX::/64                 link#2                        U           em1
MYIPV6PREFIX:3::5                 link#2                        UHS         lo0
fe80::%em0/64                     link#1                        U           em0
fe80::290:27ff:feee:a042%em0      link#1                        UHS         lo0
fe80::%em1/64                     link#2                        U           em1
fe80::290:27ff:feee:a043%em1      link#2                        UHS         lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                     link#8                        U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0                       link#8                        UHS         lo0
fe80::%ovpns1/64                  link#9                        U        ovpns1
fe80::290:27ff:feee:a042%ovpns1   link#9                        UHS         lo0
ff01::%em0/32                     fe80::290:27ff:feee:a042%em0  U           em0
ff01::%em1/32                     fe80::290:27ff:feee:a043%em1  U           em1
ff01::%lo0/32                     ::1                           U           lo0
ff01::%ovpns1/32                  fe80::290:27ff:feee:a042%ovpns1 U        ovpns1
ff02::%em0/32                     fe80::290:27ff:feee:a042%em0  U           em0
ff02::%em1/32                     fe80::290:27ff:feee:a043%em1  U           em1
ff02::%lo0/32                     ::1                           U           lo0
ff02::%ovpns1/32                  fe80::290:27ff:feee:a042%ovpns1 U        ovpns1
```

Comment: I don't see a default route (`::/0`) in the routing table.

Comment: The tunnel was removed during troubleshooting. When it's set up it works properly between the router and  the rest of the ipv6 internet, and the tunnel provider can ping / scan the LAN IP from the server side tunnel IP. What's not working is the on-link connection to the em1 network: 

MYIPV6PREFIX::/64                 link#2                        U           em1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If someone else has the same issue, this was resolved by deleting my Captive Portal configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvotes. I'm the asker, that's what fixed the issue. Since there was no mention in the firewall or other logs of the problem it was difficult to troubleshoot and therefore may be valuable to the next guy.